# When to use shared libraries for a web framework?

Tags: web-development, web-applications, performance, libraries, web-framework

**tl;dr:**

I've found myself hosting a bunch of sites running on the same web framework (symfony 1.4). Would it be helpful if I moved all of the shared library code into the same directory and shared it across the sites?

**more**

I see some advantages to this:

- Each site takes up less disk space
- Library updates (an unlikely scenario) can take place across all sites

I also see some disadvantages, mostly in terms of a single point of failure and the inability to have sites using different versions of the framework.

My real concern, though, is performance. I hypothesize that I will see a performance increase, since the PHP code will already be cached for all sites when they call the framework. Is this a correct hypothesis?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the loss in flexibility could exceed the benefit of performance increase, if any. The need of a sudden upgrade or downgrade of some components can happen at any time and with common libraries you'd be greatly limited in this sense. Moreover, any site has its own life and should then be kept completely separate from others (through chroots, virtual machines, jails) for security reasons.